# Turned off Compatibility mode, went from 80 to 90. Getting weird WITH errors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have been running a SQL Server 2005 database in compatibility mode, moved down to compatibility level 80 (SQL Server 2000).

We really need to start using table UDF's and have one particular stored procedure that's dynamic and we need to use `varchar(MAX)`. So we're testing turning off compatibility mode and running database in native 2005 mode.

When I did that on our test copy I am getting errors when I run stored procedures that were running fine at level 80. The errors are related to the `WITH` statement. I have a CTE in the stored procedure but the branch of code that's executing is not even touching that and including it in the SQL that's getting executed. I put a semicolon before the `WITH`. The problem seems to possibly be my `WITH (NOLOCK)` statements? But they're not CTEs.

Error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Umm, SQL Server 2000 didn't support common table expressions.  You sure about the before/after compatibility mode settings?

Comment: You need to share the code that's throwing the error, there's no point in us guessing what it might be.

Comment: ;with x as (select 1 y) select * from x <--- this will fail in sql-server 2000. It only works in sqlserver 2005+. Going back to older versions of sqlserver very risky.

Comment: If you are running SQL 2k5 in compatibility mode 80 (SQL 2000) then CTE's DO work.  I don't know why but I remember reading about it a while back and I know I'm using them in several places without issue in SQL 25k but Compat Mode 80.

Comment: I will get a code example posted

Comment: Well, I learned something new today.  It appears that CTE's will work on SQL 2005 with the db set to SQL 2000 compatibility mode.  http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/558238/setting-database-compatibility-level-lower-doesnt-appear-to-function-as-expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out what is going on.  If you are using CTE's and WITH(NOLOCK), if you use the WITH(NOLOCK) first you need to terminate the CTE's WITH statement.

This works fine...

```
WITH cteAreaCOdes(AreaCode, State)
AS
(
SELECT AreaCode, State from tblAreaCodes
)

SELECT * FROM tblCustomers WITH(NOLOCK)

SELECT * FROM cteAreaCOdes WITH(NOLOCK)
```

This does not...

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomers WITH(NOLOCK)

WITH cteAreaCOdes(AreaCode, State)
AS
(
SELECT AreaCode, State from tblAreaCodes
)

SELECT * FROM cteAreaCOdes WITH(NOLOCK)
```

Throws the error...

Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I then removed the WITH from tblCustomers and just used (NOLOCK) because WITH isn't necessary in 2k5, but that didn't work either.

Throws the error...

Msg 336, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'cteAreaCOdes'. If this is intended to be a common table expression, you need to explicitly terminate the previous statement with a semi-colon.

Removing (NOLOCK) completely and just running a simple SELECT statement throws same error.  So basically if I'm using a CTE I need to terminate it if ANY other SELECT statement comes before it.

This actually shouldn't have been so confusing, the simple rule of thumb to terminate all WITH statements would have fixed all my issues, the problem arose because SQL2k5 in compatibility mode 80 (SQL 2k) allows ALL of those statements I tried above to work just fine.

So it allows CTE's (which SQL 2k does not), however, it doesn't require any termination of the WITH statements anywhere.

Comment: Oh, and one other thing to metntion.  I was getting this error and couldn't figure it out after I terminated everything in my sproc.  I had a UDF I was calling that had a CTE in it, that was causing the error.  Again, this all worked fine in SQL25k (80) compatibility mode.